# A particular picture copies by itself multiple times in camera roll every day

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, camera-roll

I've been using iPhone for many years now but this is the first time I've this problem.

I received a picture from a friend, who is on Android. Since then that particular picture copies by itself multiple times during the day in my camera roll.

Any idea why this may be happening?
A virus, malware?

I am on iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3.

Comment: I doubt it's a virus. How did you get that picture? Via mail?

Comment: Some third-party messaging applications copy photos to the Camera Roll after receiving them, such as WhatsApp. Assuming you received it in a third-party application, there may be a bug in that application causing it to be saved repeatedly.

Comment: Did you enable iCloud Photo Library (from Settings > iCloud > Photos). I doubt that it has something to do with it but try disabling that and seeing whether the photo continues to re-appear.

Comment: The Android is replicating itself like Agent Smith. And so it beings…

Comment: Thanks everyone! It got fixed after removing the photo from the application itself.

Comment: Hi Yordan. I made an answer for this after the comments. Could you upvote it & mark it as correct - for future Googlers. [I don't get any points for it as I set it to Community Wiki, but it saves the post just hanging forever with no accepted answer]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Porting this to a community wiki answer so it doesn't remain hanging, as I've seen similar questions asked a couple of times recently</sub>

Some third-party messaging applications copy photos to the Camera Roll after receiving them, such as WhatsApp. Assuming you received it in a third-party application, there may be a bug in that application causing it to be saved repeatedly.

Try removing the photo from any 3rd party app it may have originated in.